# Changing throttle config in SharePoint 2010 Management Shell

Tags: sharepoint-2010, threshold, throttling, external-contenttype

I' woring in my dev environment and I have just set up an External Content Type through SharePoint Designer.

My list returns and error and from what I can gather it is because It is trying to return more items than the limit in the throttle config

I have tested it with a list with 60 items and it works fine.

I have attempted to update it using the command

Set-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig

It asks for the following values

Identity:
Maximum: 100000
Default: 12000

I get this error

```
cmdlet Set-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Identity:
Maximum:
Default:
Set-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Can
not convert the "" value of type "System.String" to type "Microsoft.SharePoint.
BusinessData.SharedService.ThrottleConfig".
At line:1 char:40
+ set-spbusinessdatacatalogthrottleconfig <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-SPBusinessDataCatalogT
   hrottleConfig], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.SharePo
   int.BusinessData.SharedService.SPSetSPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig
```

How do I find out what "identity" I need to put in?

Everything I try returns the same message.

Any advice or alternative way to increase the throttle threshold?

Answer (score 1):

Set-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig cmdlet needs to know what configuration you are changing. Try this:

```
$bdcProxy = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | where {$_.GetType().FullName -eq ('Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.SharedService.' + 'BdcServiceApplicationProxy')}
$dbRule = Get-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig -Scope Database -ThrottleType Items -ServiceApplicationProxy $bdcProxy
Set-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig -Identity $dbRule -Maximum 100000 -Default 12000
```